# Anaconda3 - instalar paquete matplotlib.ppylot

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda

En Windows 10, tengo instalado Anaconda3 (incluye Conda 4.4.6 y python 3.6.3). Necesito instalar el módulo `matplotlib.ppylot`.

Ejecuto `conda install matplotlib.ppylot` y obtengo el aviso que adjunto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo puedo seguir para conseguir instalar este paquete?.**

Dentro del directorio de Anaconda3, he ejecutado `conda > install > matplotlib`

Después de actualizar `etc.`, continúa dando el mismo error al ejecutar un script en jupyter notebook o en spyder.

Seguidamente he desinstalado Anaconda3 y lo he vuelto a instalar. A continuación he instalado el paquete matplotlib utilizando conda: (`conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib`).

Entro en jupyter y el error se reproduce.

Me situo en la consola de anaconda, dentro del directorio ANACONDA3.

Ejecuto python y escribo import matplotlib e import numpy. No me da ningún error.

Spyder y jupiter notebook contiúan dandome el error

> "No module named matplotlib.ppylot.

He descubierto que el problema estaba en el script y no en la instalación del programa. No entiendo el por qué, pero lo cierto es que, el script

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.ppylot import plt
plot([0,1,0,1])
```

Devuelve error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.ppylot'

Si lo modifico

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0,1,0,1])
```

Ya no nos devuelve ese error.

Answer (score 1):

Ya intentaste con :

```
conda install matplotlib
```

[Fuente](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#building-on-linux) (Hasta el ultimo apartado inferior)